# 2.5D Delaunay triangulation in Python CGAL

Tags: python-3.7, cgal

I have successfully installed the cgal-swig bindings and I can create either 2D or 3D triangulations as in the [examples](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/blob/master/examples/python/triangulation_prog1.py). The documentation and examples only use either a 2D or 3D triangulation.

However I have a set of 2.5D points being `x,y,depth`. I want a 2D Delaunay triangulation with `z/depth/height` being a property or attribute of the vertices. From my understanding, a `Delaunay_triangulation_2` only takes 2D `Points_2` objects and a `Triangulation_3` generates tetrahedra and not triangles.

I think these solutions would almost solve my problems:

- [CGAL 2.5D Triangulation Attach vertex info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786974/cgal-2-5d-triangulation-attach-vertex-info)
- [Retrieve z from a constrained delaunay triangulation of Projection_traits_xy_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891713/retrieve-z-from-a-constrained-delaunay-triangulation-of-projection-traits-xy-3)
- [Constrained delaunay triangulation with Projection_traits_xy_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874406/constrained-delaunay-triangulation-with-projection-traits-xy-3?rq=1)

However, the proposed solutions are in C++ (which I do not understand). Is it possible to use the same approach using `projection_traits_xy_3` using the `cgal-swig` bindings in Python? Or is there another way I can (efficiently) link a collection of CGAL Point_2 to a lookup table with more information? In the end I would be using it for e.g. terrain interpolation etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

There are no bindings of projection_traits in CGAL for now.